# Regular expression for matching latitude/longitude coordinates?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression for matching latitude/longitude coordinates. For matching a double-precision number I've used `(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)`, and tried to combine that into a single expression:

```
^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\w*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$
```

I expected this to match a double, a comma, perhaps some space, and another double, but it doesn't seem to work. Specifically it only works if there's NO space, not one or more. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Whitespace is \s, not \w

```
^(-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$
```

See if this works

Comment: I had to use dot instead of comma:
/^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?) hereAdot . endMod \s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$/

Comment: It accepts values out side the allowed range for lats and longs. eg, 91,181

Comment: This works for x/y-coordinates of projected spatial reference systems as well

Answer (score 284):

This one will strictly match latitude and longitude values that fall within the correct range:

```
^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$
```

Matches

- +90.0, -127.554334
- 45, 180
- -90, -180
- -90.000, -180.0000
- +90, +180
- 47.1231231, 179.99999999

Doesn't Match

- -90., -180.
- +90.1, -100.111
- -91, 123.456
- 045, 180

Comment: Modified to accept white-space on both sides of the comma: ^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?)\s*,\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$

Comment: Thank you. Also, if you want to capture the polarity (+/-) just add parentheses around both `[+-]` groups.

Comment: I changed this to get just that lat lon in the capturing groups by using the `?:` non capturing group syntax, as well as capture polarity `(^[-+]?(?:[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d+)?|90(?:\.0+)?)),\s*([-+]?(?:180(?:\.0+)?|(?:(?:1[0-7]\d)|(?:[1-9]?\d))(?:\.\d+)?))$`

Comment: My two cents on this nice regex: added named capturing groups based on @narthur157 and removed some unecessary non capturing groups: `(?<lat>^[-+]?(?:[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d+)?|90(?:\.0+)?))\s*,\s*(?<lng>[-+]?(?:180(?:\.0+)?|(?:1[0-7]\d|[1-9]?\d)(?:\.\d+)?))$`

Answer (score 161):

I am using these ones (decimal format, with 6 decimal digits):

### Latitude

```
^(\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$
```

[image: Latitude Regular expression visualization]

### Longitude

```
^(\+|-)?(?:180(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$
```

[image: Longitude Regular expression visualization]

---

[Here](https://gist.github.com/ferrarimarco/e73e07d6664281a81d95) is a gist that tests both, reported here also, for ease of access. It's a Java TestNG test. You need Slf4j, Hamcrest and Lombok to run it:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;

import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Slf4j
public class LatLongValidationTest {

    protected static final String LATITUDE_PATTERN="^(\\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$";
    protected static final String LONGITUDE_PATTERN="^(\\+|-)?(?:180(?:(?:\\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$";

    @Test
    public void latitudeTest(){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
        double step = 0.01;
        Double latitudeToTest = -90.0;

        while(latitudeToTest <= 90.0){
            boolean result = df.format(latitudeToTest).matches(LATITUDE_PATTERN);
            log.info("Latitude: tested {}. Result (matches regex): {}", df.format(latitudeToTest), result);
            assertThat(result, is(true));
            latitudeToTest += step;
        }

        latitudeToTest = -90.1;

        while(latitudeToTest >= -200.0){
            boolean result = df.format(latitudeToTest).matches(LATITUDE_PATTERN);
            log.info("Latitude: tested {}. Result (matches regex): {}", df.format(latitudeToTest), result);
            assertThat(result, is(false));
            latitudeToTest -= step;
        }

        latitudeToTest = 90.01;

        while(latitudeToTest <= 200.0){
            boolean result = df.format(latitudeToTest).matches(LATITUDE_PATTERN);
        log.info("Latitude: tested {}. Result (matches regex): {}", df.format(latitudeToTest), result);
            assertThat(result, is(false));
            latitudeToTest += step;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void longitudeTest(){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.######");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
        double step = 0.01;
        Double longitudeToTest = -180.0;

        while(longitudeToTest <= 180.0){
            boolean result = df.format(longitudeToTest).matches(LONGITUDE_PATTERN);
            log.info("Longitude: tested {}. Result (matches regex): {}", df.format(longitudeToTest), result);
            assertThat(result, is(true));
            longitudeToTest += step;
        }

        longitudeToTest = -180.01;

        while(longitudeToTest >= -300.0){
            boolean result = df.format(longitudeToTest).matches(LONGITUDE_PATTERN);
            log.info("Longitude: tested {}. Result (matches regex): {}", df.format(longitudeToTest), result);
            assertThat(result, is(false));
            longitudeToTest -= step;
        }

        longitudeToTest = 180.01;

        while(longitudeToTest <= 300.0){
            boolean result = df.format(longitudeToTest).matches(LONGITUDE_PATTERN);
            log.info("Longitude: tested {}. Result (matches regex): {}", df.format(longitudeToTest), result);
            assertThat(result, is(false));
            longitudeToTest += step;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a really nice regex! But is it possible to shorten it down a little? :) If it can't, it's okey but shorten code are always welcome :)

Comment: @ErikEdgren I did not find a way to shorten it :(

Comment: What is the website url

Comment: for my latitude and longitude is -22.4973154 and -44.0980778

I changed {1,6} to {1,7} and worked

Comment: @basickarl there is a few websites. one of them is https://regexper.com/

Answer (score 22):

Actually Alix Axel, above regex is wrong in latitude, longitude ranges point of view.

Latitude measurements range from –90° to +90°
Longitude measurements range from –180° to +180°

So the regex given below validates more accurately.
Also, as per my thought no one should restrict decimal point in latitude/longitude.

```
^([-+]?\d{1,2}([.]\d+)?),\s*([-+]?\d{1,3}([.]\d+)?)$
```

OR for Objective C

```
^([-+]?\\d{1,2}([.]\\d+)?),\\s*([-+]?\\d{1,3}([.]\\d+)?)$
```

Comment: It accepts`99` for `Latitude`, while `99` is out of range of `-90, +90` and so invalid.

Answer (score 18):

```
^-?[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,10})?$
```

Regex breakdown:

```
^-?[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,10})?$
```

`-?`           # accept negative values

`^`            # Start of string

`[0-9]{1,3}`   # Match 1-3 digits (i. e. 0-999)

`(?:`          # Try to match...

`\.`          # a decimal point

`[0-9]{1,10}`  # followed by one to 10 digits (i. e. 0-9999999999)

`)?`           # ...optionally

`$`            # End of string

Comment: I think yours is the most elegant. Firstly, it worked immediately without having to edit and replace escape characters. Secondly, it is short. Thirdly, it is easy to understand.

Comment: the most simple and correct answer... it can be simplied to ^-?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,10})?$

Answer (score 13):

[@macro-ferrari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653462/marco-ferrari) I did find a way to shorten it, and without look aheads in the light of all recent talks about [regex engines](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)

```
const LAT_RE = /^[+-]?(([1-8]?[0-9])(\.[0-9]{1,6})?|90(\.0{1,6})?)$/;
```

[image]

```
const LONG_RE = /^[+-]?((([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(\.[0-9]{1,6})?)|180(\.0{1,6})?)$/;
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation, btw how did u get this flow control any specific software u used. this one https://regexper.com?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a more strict version:

```
^([-+]?\d{1,2}[.]\d+),\s*([-+]?\d{1,3}[.]\d+)$
```

- Latitude = `-90` -- `+90`
- Longitude = `-180` -- `+180`

Comment: I believe that {1,2} should come first, then {1,3}

Comment: @Arjan: Fixed, I always confuse the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
^(\()([-+]?)([\d]{1,2})(((\.)(\d+)(,)))(\s*)(([-+]?)([\d]{1,3})((\.)(\d+))?(\)))$
```

Check it out at:

http://regexpal.com/

Paste the expression in the top box, then put things like this in the bottom box:

```
(80.0123, -34.034)
(80.0123)
(80.a)
(980.13, 40)
(99.000, 122.000)
```

Regex breakdown:

```
^                    # The string must start this way (there can't be anything before). 
    (\()             # An opening parentheses (escaped with a backslash).
    ([-+]?)          # An optional minus, or an optional plus.
    ([\d]{1,2})      # 1 or 2 digits (0-9).
    (                # Start of a sub-pattern.
        (            # Start of a sub-pattern.
            (\.)     # A dot (escaped with a backslash).
            (\d+)    # One or more digits (0-9).
            (,)      # A comma.
        )            # End of a sub-pattern.
    )                # End of a sub-pattern.
    (\s*)            # Zero or more spaces.
    (                # Start of a sub-pattern.
        ([-+]?)      # An optional minus, or an optional plus. 
        ([\d]{1,3})  # 1 to 3 digits (0-9).
        (            # Start of a pattern.
            (\.)     # A dot (escaped with a backslash).
            (\d+)    # One or more digits (0-9).
        )?           # End of an optional pattern.
        (\))         # A closing parenthesis (escaped with a backkslash).
    )                # End of a pattern
$                    # The string must end this way (there can't be anything after).
```

Now, what this does NOT do is restrict itself to this range:

```
(-90 to +90, and -180 to +180)
```

Instead, it simple restricts itself to this range:

```
(-99 to +99, -199 to +199)
```

But the point is mainly just to break down each piece of the expression.

Answer (score 7):

Python:

Latitude: `result = re.match("^[+-]?((90\.?0*$)|(([0-8]?[0-9])\.?[0-9]*$))", '-90.00001')`

Longitude: `result = re.match("^[+-]?((180\.?0*$)|(((1[0-7][0-9])|([0-9]{0,2}))\.?[0-9]*$))", '-0.0000')`

Latitude should fail in the example.

Answer (score 7):

**Regex shorten [@marco-ferrari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653462/marco-ferrari) solution by replacing the multiple use of [0-9] with subset of [0-9]. Also removed unnecessary quantifiers such as ?: from various places**

```
lat  "^([+-])?(?:90(?:\\.0{1,6})?|((?:|[1-8])[0-9])(?:\\.[0-9]{1,6})?)$";
long "^([+-])?(?:180(?:\\.0{1,6})?|((?:|[1-9]|1[0-7])[0-9])(?:\\.[0-9]{1,6})?)$";


**Matches for Lat**

Valid between -90 to +90 with up to 6 decimals.

**Matches for Long**

Valid between -180 to +180 with up to 6 decimals.
```

Answer (score 4):

This would work for format like this: 31 ͦ 37.4' E

```
^[-]?\d{1,2}[ ]*ͦ[ ]*\d{1,2}\.?\d{1,2}[ ]*\x27[ ]*\w$
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're using \w (word character) where you ought to be using \s (whitespace).  Word characters typically consist of [A-Za-z0-9_], so that excludes your space, which then further fails to match on the optional minus sign or a digit.

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby**

Longitude *-179.99999999..180*

```
/^(-?(?:1[0-7]|[1-9])?\d(?:\.\d{1,8})?|180(?:\.0{1,8})?)$/ === longitude.to_s
```

Latitude *-89.99999999..90*

```
/^(-?[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d{1,8})?|90(?:\.0{1,8})?)$/ === latitude.to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete and simple method in objective C for checking correct pattern for latitude and longitude is:

```
 -( BOOL )textIsValidValue:(NSString*) searchedString
{
    NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);
    NSError  *error = nil;
    NSString *pattern = @"^[-+]?([1-8]?\\d(\\.\\d+)?|90(\\.0+)?),\\s*[-+]?(180(\\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\\d)|([1-9]?\\d))(\\.\\d+)?)$";
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:searchedString options:0 range: searchedRange];
    return match ? YES : NO;
}
```

where **searchedString** is the input that user would enter in the respective textfield.

Answer (score 1):

#### PHP

Here is the PHP's version (input values are: `$latitude` and `$longitude`):

```
$latitude_pattern  = '/\A[+-]?(?:90(?:\.0{1,18})?|\d(?(?<=9)|\d?)\.\d{1,18})\z/x';
$longitude_pattern = '/\A[+-]?(?:180(?:\.0{1,18})?|(?:1[0-7]\d|\d{1,2})\.\d{1,18})\z/x';
if (preg_match($latitude_pattern, $latitude) && preg_match($longitude_pattern, $longitude)) {
  // Valid coordinates.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this one enforces 3 numbers after the comma to avoid false matches:

`(?<latitude>-?\d+\.\d{3,10}),(?<longitude>-?\d+\.\d{3,10})`

Answer (score 0):

### Latitude

Valid between -90 to +90 up to 9 decimals.

`^([+-])?(?:90(?:\\.0{1,6})?|((?:|[1-8])[0-9])(?:\\.[0-9]{1,9})?)$`

### Longitude

Valid between -180 to +180 up to 9 decimals.

`^([+-])?(?:180(?:\\.0{1,6})?|((?:|[1-9]|1[0-7])[0-9])(?:\\.[0-9]{1,9})?)$`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
(?<!\d)([-+]?(?:[1-8]?\d(?:\.\d+)?|90(?:\.0+)?)),\s*([-+]?(?:180(?:\.0+)?|(?:(?:1[0-7]\d)|(?:[1-9]?\d))(?:\.\d+)?))(?!\d)`
```

Comment: Pure code answers are rarely a good idea. Please add some descriptive text to your answer.

Comment: works great: validates accurately, and picks out lat, long from any surrounding text.  Does not, however, limit the number of significant digits it allows after the decimal point.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
var latExp = /^(?=.)-?((8[0-5]?)|([0-7]?[0-9]))?(?:\.[0-9]{1,20})?$/;
var lngExp = /^(?=.)-?((0?[8-9][0-9])|180|([0-1]?[0-7]?[0-9]))?(?:\.[0-9]{1,20})?$/;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
^[-+]?(([0-8]\\d|\\d)(\\.\\d+)?|90(\\.0+)?)$,\s*^[-+]?((1[0-7]\\d(\\.\\d+)?)|(180(\\.0+)?)|(\\d\\d(\\.\\d+)?)|(\\d(\\.\\d+)?))$
```