# regex for latitude longitude pairs

Tags: c#, regex

I draw a line on a google map than I create a string like:

> (-25.368819800291383,130.55809472656256)(-25.507716386730266,131.05797265625006)      (-24.89637614190406,131.49193261718756)(-24.582068950590272,130.31090234375006)

the first value is the latitude, the second the longitude. I assign a hidden field value tothis string so I can acces it on the server.

How can I retrieve the latitude and longitude numbers?

I was trying

```
 Match match = Regex.Match(points, @"(^(0|(-(((0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d+)|([1-9]\d*))))$,^(0|(-(((0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d+)|([1-9]\d*))))$)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: May be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates

Comment: **How can I retrieve the latitude and longitude numbers?**  - You don't need a regular expression to do this.  I would argue it would be faster just to use `String.Split`

Comment: @Ramhound. Some string manipulation sounds workable as well. But after the split you should still do some more parsing right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
\((?<lat>[-\d.]+),(?<long>[-\d.]+)\)
```

I like to use named groups here. To get only the latitudes use

```
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\((?<lat>[-\d.]+),(?<long>[-\d.]+)\)");
    Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResult.Success) {
        Console.WriteLine(matchResult.Groups["lat"].Value));
        matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates)). One of the issues with your regex is that you are using `^` and `$` twice. These denote the start and end of the string thus in your case your regex will never work.

The regex above should extract the digits and make them available through the use of groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(points, @"(-?\d+\.\d+)+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

For your input, it will yield 8 results, each result = Longitude OR Latitude

```
Match match = Regex.Match(points, @"((-?\d+\.\d+)+,?){2}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Will yield 4 results, each result is a pair of the form **Latitude, Longitude**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
p = re.compile('([+-]*\d*[\.]*\d*), ([+-]*\d*[\.]*\d*)')
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    try:
        z = str(input())
        z = z[1:len(z)-1]
        zz = re.findall(p, z)
        zz = zz[0]
        x = zz[0]
        y = zz[1]
        if(x[0] == '+' or x[0] == '-'):
            x = x[1:]
        if(y[0] == '+' or y[0] == '-'):
            y = y[1:]
        if(x[len(x)-1] == '.' or y[len(y)-1] == '.'):
            print("Invalid")
            continue
        if((len(x) > 1 and x[0] == '0' and x[1] != '.') or (len(y) > 1 and y[0] == '0' and y[1] != '.')):
            print("Invalid")
            continue
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        if(x >= -90.0 and x <= 90.0 and y >= -180.0 and y <= 180.0):
            print("Valid")
        else:
            print("Invalid")
    except:
        print("Invalid")
```