# Regular Expression for a string of latitude longitude pairs

Tags: regex

I am receiving an input like this in my program

> lat1,long1;lat2,long2;lat3,long3

latitude longitude pairs separated by columns.

No I want to validate this input so that i may not receive wrong data.

I have created a regular expression:

```
((^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?));?)
```

problem is it only validates a single pair not a string of pairs separated by ; as i wish.

If you could help me come up with an expression to validate my data I would be grateful.

Comment: Please post a sample of your data.

Comment: @Asad 
Example of vaild data:
(1) 33.44,34.43
(2) 33.44,34.43;43.44,44.43;53.54,34.43

Examples of invalid data:
(1) 33.44,37.45,36.46
(2) 33.56,46.77;56

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for matching latitude/longitude coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression check only one pair at the start of the string folowed by one column.

You can try this :

```
^\-?\d+(\.\d+)?,\-?\d+(\.\d+)?(;\-?\d+(\.\d+)?,\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)*$
```

Thats your regex (without some brackets inutiles) folowed by 0 or more times a column and a pair.

[A test with your 4 examples.](http://rubular.com/r/G4KD6HTPiQ)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
(-?[\d\.]+,-?[\d\.]+)+;?+
```

I tried it on [Rubular.com (permalink)](http://rubular.com/r/ZXlUF6tll1), with the test string as following:

```
-10,10;10.5,-10.337
```

Result?

```
Match 1
1.  -10,10
Match 2
1.  10.5,-10.337
```

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work with these data:

(1) 33.44,37.45,36.46 (2) 33.56,46.77;56

Comment: Define not work - it'll only capture the valid values. @khobab :)

Comment: Means when I check ita against above two values. It verifies them as a match where they are not. BTW the answer above had all what i was looking for ;), thanx for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following pattern, which can also accept values like `.2` along with `0.2`.

```
^-?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+),-?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)(;-?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+),-?(\d+(\.\d+)?|\.\d+)){2}$
```

Here's the breakdown.

```
^                 # beginning of string
    -?                # optional minus sign
    (                 # either
        \d+(\.\d+)?   # an integer with an optional decimal part
        |             # or
        \.\d+         # a decimal number
    )
    ,                 # a comma
    -?                # optional minus sign
    (                 # either
        \d+(\.\d+)?   # an integer and an optional decimal part
        |             # or
        \.\d+         # a decimal number
    )
    (
        ;                 # a semicolon
        -?                # optional minus sign
        (                 # either
            \d+(\.\d+)?   # an integer and an optional decimal part
            |             # or
            \.\d+         # a decimal number
        )
        ,                 # a comma
        -?                # optional minus sign
        (                 # either
            \d+(\.\d+)?   # an integer and an optional decimal part
            |             # or
            \.\d+         # a decimal number
        )
    ){2}              # with 2 repetitions (of the pattern)
$                 # end of string
```