# How Can I Parse CSV in C#

Tags: c#

I have some point coordinates like below:

> -123.118069008,49.2761419674,0 -123.116802056,49.2752350159,0 -123.115385004,49.2743520328,0 -123.114912944,49.2738039982,..............
>   -123.118069008,49.2761419674,0

Can you please let me know how I can use C# to create something like this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(-123.118069008,49.2761419674),
new google.maps.LatLng(-123.116802056,49.2752350159),
.....
new google.maps.LatLng(-123.118069008,49.2761419674)];
```

As you can see I need to:

1. Add the "new google.maps.LatLng(),"
2. Remove the 0 from -123.118069008,49.2761419674,0
3. Parse it until the last line which terminate with ;

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: A regular expression would be your easiest solution. [This question has you halfway there.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest way to do it that I know of...

```
        var txt = "-123.118069008,49.2761419674,0 -123.116802056,49.2752350159,0 -123.115385004,49.2743520328,0";
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var group in txt.Split(' '))
        {
            var parts = group.Split(',');
            var lat = double.Parse(parts[0]);
            var lng = double.Parse(parts[1]);
            if (output.Length > 0)
                output.AppendLine(",");
            output.Append("new google.maps.LatLng("+lat+","+lng+")");
        }
        MessageBox.Show("["+output+"]");
```

The result is...

[new google.maps.LatLng(-123.118069008,49.2761419674),

new google.maps.LatLng(-123.116802056,49.2752350159),

new google.maps.LatLng(-123.115385004,49.2743520328)]

Answer (score 0):

Untested and not compiled, but this should get you started

```
var items = data.Split(',');
for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i = i + 2)
{
    var lat = int.Parse(items[i].Replace("0-","-"));
    var lng = int.Parse(items[i+1]);
}
```

You'll want to do array bounds checking, etc, hopefully this still helps.

Comment: Thank Nate, I am going to test this