# Validate latitude using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I restrict an input field for enter latitude using javascript?

The following is the piece nof code which i have tried.

```
$('#latitude').on( "keypress",function (e) {
        var keypress = e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode; 
        var key = String.fromCharCode(keypress);
        var regEx = /^[-|+]?[0-9]{0,2}(.[0-9]{0,6})?$/;

        var txt = $(this).val() + key;
        if (!regEx.test(txt)) {
            if(keypress != 8){
                e.preventDefault();
            }else{
            }
        }else{

        }
    });
```

Here i found the issue that i can enter a special character at the first position. Please help me...

Comment: What is your desired lat format?

Comment: The desired latitude formats are -10.234545,12.357347,+12.343646,0.123345,18

Comment: try http://jsbin.com/aCodadO/17/

Answer (score 0):

In your validation also include the following line:

```
if (!regEx.test(txt) && !isNaN(txt)) { .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, also note that `N` and `S` can also be included in latitude

```
"^(?:90|[0-8][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9][NS]$"
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered here [Regular expression for matching latitude/longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates).

It suggests the following regular expression:
`^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$`