# Regex checking lat/lon in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm such a newb in regex, but still...
I based my test on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903756/using-regular-expression-to-validate-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-then-dis) post.

I have this simple regex :

```
^-?([1]?[1-7][1-9]|[1]?[1-8][0]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.{1}\d{1,6}
```

In [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/), if I test it with **88.5** for example, it matches.

In my JS file, I have :

```
var lonRegex = new RegExp("^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,6}");
var check = lonRegex.test(88.5); // hardcoded for demo
console.log(check) // output false
```

I can't guess why it's always returning me false, whatever the value is a number or a string like "88.5".

Comment: This has something to do with how regex parts are escaped when creating a regex object from a string. `/^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,6}/.test(88.5)` will return `true`

Comment: Don't construct a regexp from a string, just use a regex literal (`/.../`). Also, don't check numbers with a regexp, just check them with arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape some characters when creating a `RegExp` object from a string. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description):

> When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are necessary.

In your case, this will work (note the double \ for \d and .):

```
var lonRegex = new RegExp("^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\\.{1}\\d{1,6}");
var check = lonRegex.test(88.5); // hardcoded for demo
console.log(check) // output true
```

Comment: Equivalently, you could use `var lonRegex = /^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,6}/;`.

Comment: Also, it gives the wrong results for (for example) `0.5` and `90.5`.