# Android split Text / Numbers from SMS string

Tags: android, string, sms, strip

im making a gps tracking program and i receive an sms message with the following content

smsMessage="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=42.396068,13.45201,17   phone is outside the area"

Could anybody be so kind and tell me how i can split out only the needed longitude and the latitude from the sms string ?

thanx in advance

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Hi 42.396068    and 13.45201,17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
String s = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=42.396068,13.45201,17 phone is outside the area";
String parts[] = s.replaceAll("^.*?=|\\s.*", "").split(",(?=[-+]?\\d+\\.\\d+)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

output:

```
[42.396068, 13.45201,17]
```

Comment: hi thanx for your answer so the results will be in parts[0] and parts[1| i quess ..i will try this out

Answer (score 0):

You need regular expression to get your latitude and longitude from the given text. Here it is:

```
[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)
```

Matches

- +90.0, -127.554334 45, 180
- -90, -180
- -90.000, -180.0000
- +90, +180
- 47.1231231, 179.99999999

Doesn't Match

- -90., -180.
- +90.1, -100.111
- -91, 123.456
- 045, 180

Source: [Regular expression for matching latitude/longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates)

Comment: hi im not very familiar with regular expressions

Comment: could you give me a code example how to get only these two values out of the string ?