# Regular Expression for geographic coordinates (Latitude/Longitude)

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to ask if the following two regular expressions are good for describing coordinates. Because latitude has just 90 degrees and longitude 180, I have created two seperate regular expressions:

**Latitude regex:**

```
\A[+-]?((9[0]?|[0-8][0-9]?([.,][0-9]+)?))\z
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6SOVr9MTf-Tx2ScZ)

**Longitude regex:**

```
\A[+-]?(180|(1[0-7][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})([.,][0-9]+)?)\z
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6BK1WdKnY_rNHfnj)

I've tested them with some coordinates in [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com). I wanted to ask if I miss something important that wouldn't describe valid coordinates.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates

Comment: Yes I've seen this but I wanted to have a more general regex without the special metacharacters of ruby

Comment: Longitude is wrong: http://www.rubular.com/r/Af7AcJIxuV

Comment: Hi @mudasobwa you are right! Do you know a solution?

Comment: I've updated the longitude regex now. Thanks to @mudasobwa again!

Comment: Tobias, you should provide the input you want to match

Comment: Hi @Thomas! As I said it should match different types of coordinates. For example +180, -180, 19.1912, etc. But I don't know if there is something additional to care for what I forgot in my regexes.

Comment: So you want us to (try to) take down your regex, that's it?

Comment: If you see something that doesn't describe all types of latitudes or longitudes, yes. I don't want you to go and try a lot of different coordinates. I just wanted to know if people with some more experience with geographic coordinates see something that isn't correct for coordinates.

Comment: Regular expressions can be notoriously hard to read. In ruby you can break regular expressions on multiple lines and add comments to make it easier on yourself and your fellow programmers.

Comment: Thanks @R.Peereboom for the info! How would you break a regular expression on multiple lines? Always when I start a subexpression?

Comment: @Tobias It depends, you can find a rather terrible example in the [ruby Regexp docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Free-Spacing+Mode+and+Comments). Here is a lattitude example, you might have to copy paste in a text editor (I've numbered the lines): 1.\A                # start of string
2.[+-]?             # optional sign
3.(
4.(9[0]?|[0-8][0-9]?# Number upto 90 (can be simplified)
5.([.,][0-9]+)?)    # optional fraction
6.)
7.\z                # end of string

Answer (score 0):

The **Latitude regex** does not suit the picture and its Debuggex Demo; while picture and demo are correct, the shown regex fails to match e. g. `9.0`.
The **Longitude regex** and its picture and demo are correct.