# Validation for latitude and longitude values using ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation, ng-pattern

I have used **ng-pattern**

`/^[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]+)?$/`

for validate latitude and longitude values, but this pattern is not allowing me to enter negative values.

Latitude and longitude values contains negative and decimal values 
Can you please suggest me one good ng-pattern for my requirements.

Example values are given below

`234.546655`, `3.5766876`, `12345.766566`

I need validation for this type values. It should allow negative,positive,decimal and all numbers

Comment: For longitude, you don't need a value larger than ±180, and latitude no larger than ±90.

Answer (score 4):

This is a complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690202/6359058

For your example: [-+]? is required for either - or +

```
/^[-+]?[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

Comment: You should mark the question as a duplicate rather than answer with a link.

Comment: Thanks  @ColinFiat it's working

Comment: Thanks RobG. Can you tell me how to do that? I can't see a specific button or control.

However, the question posed was how to get the sign's included in his current regular expression. I've answered above that simple request by adding a link to a more complete answer to a question he did not ask.