# Matching longitude and latitude in a query string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url with the following query string

```
&center=37.793243,-122.421227
```

Keep in mind there are other coordinate query strings in the url. I'd simply like to grab the first pair. With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690202/3046413) I get the following:

```
str.match(/[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)/);

["37.793243,-122.421227", "37.793243", ".793243", undefined, "122.421227", undefined, "122", "122", undefined, ".421227"]
```

What would I have to do to simplify the match where it returns the `37.793243` and `-122.421227` in the array?

```
['37.793243', '-122.421227']
```

Comment: Can't you take out value corresponding to `center` and split on `,` and then take out first 2 element using `array#slice`?

Comment: regex just might be overkill and overly complex here.

Comment: I had create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/neagdcyt/) for QS to object. You can use it and the do `obj.center.split(',')`. Just a POV but its usually difficult to manipulate a string and regex can get complicated very quickly.

Comment: @HassanImam What method were you thinking along the lines of extracting the `center` value?

Comment: You can use `var parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
parsedUrl.searchParams.get("center");`

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to post this as an answer. I'd be more than happy to mark it as correct. Thanks for the suggestion either way.