# Spring MVC @PathVariable with regex

Tags: regex, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I want to restrict a @PathVariable mapping to only accept latitude/longitude valid values. For instance, the regexp for latitude is `^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,6}`. Hence, Spring sees {1} and {1,6} as path variables. Here is the code snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "@{userLatitude:^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\\.{1}\\d{1,6}},{userLongitude},{radiusOfSearchInKm}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<DTO> nearbyShops(@PathVariable double userLatitude, @PathVariable double userLongitude, @PathVariable double radiusOfSearchInKm) {
        return mappingFacade.mapShopsListToShopDTOsList(getNearbyShops(userLatitude, userLongitude, radiusOfSearchInKm));
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to escape the curly braces in the regexp so it's seen as a whole regexp. How to do that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates ?

Comment: the regexp described in that post doesn't seem to work, still i have to find a way to neutralize the accolades to restict values with 1 to 6 decimals

Comment: Try doubling each brace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not woking either! Intellij still showing ''cannot resolve PathResolve '1'" and "cannot resolve PathResolve '1,6'"