# How do I negate this Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I found this Regular Expression which only matches for valid coordinates.

```
^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$
```

(Which I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518504/regular-expression-for-matching-latitude-longitude-coordinates))

How do I negate it so it matches anything that isn't a valid coordinate? I've tried using `?!` but not matter where I put it, it doesn't seem to work

**Edit:** Edited the Regular Expression because I didn't copy it correctly

Comment: You didn't copy that regular expression correctly. Yours is making the comma optional...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to negate a whole regex like this you'd better not try to phrase this inside the regular expression. The programming language you use (in your case javascript) will have a function to match against a string. (i gues in your case its `string.matches(regex)` just negate that expression `!string.matches(regex)`.

If you want to have the whole text without the coordinates then you could do `string.replaceAll(regex, "")` and you get the text without the matching components.

Comment: In JavaScript it's `regex.test(string)`. There's also `regex.exec(string)` which is *basically* like `string.match(regex)`. Very confusing I know.

Answer (score 0):

The negation by wrapping all in a `^(?!  )` construct will work, but your regex is not correct -- you lost some essential characters, so that it has `,*` making the comma optional so that many *single* numbers will also be matched. The original (correct) regex has `,\s*` at that position in the regex. If you don't want to allow such white space, then remove `\s*`, not just `\s`...

So the opposite *test* can be done with:

```
^(?![-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$)
```

If you actually want to *capture* the line that this regex matches, append `.*` to this regex.

Comment: I've tried that, and it works for the most part. However when I try to replace the non-matched patterns, it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/tLe06rfb/

Comment: Like I wrote in the answer, when you need to *capture* the line that is wrong, then you need to append `.*` to the regex. This is what you need for your `replace` code to work: https://jsfiddle.net/4rczkx20/

Comment: It's returning me an empty string :\

Comment: Yes, that is what `replace` does when you provide as replacement string an empty string... Why is that not what you expected?

Comment: I was hoping it would replace the link and return me the coordinates, as I'm extracting the coordinates out

Comment: But wait! You are working on input that has more text, not just coordinates. But do realise that `^` in your original regex means "start of the input string". That regex is intended to verify that the **whole** input matches or not. So this is a different use case. If you want to verify *part* of a string, you need a different regex, but then your question is off.

Comment: What RegEx would I need to use to get the whole string then?

Comment: I'm lost as to what you want. Is your question really "how can I remove text that is surrounding valid coordinates?" Why then not just *match* the coordinates with the original regex, and forget about the rest?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to extract a valid coordinate from a longer string you don't need to negate the regex. You can use this regex replace:

```
let coord = str.replace(/^.*?([-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?),\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)).*$/, '$1');
```

Explanation:

- `^.*?` - is a non-greedy scan that will scan up to the first pattern found that follows; if you use `^.*` instead, you'll scan up to the last pattern (in case there is more than one); pick the one you want
- `(` ... `)` - defines a capture group, anything within the parenthesis is captured and can be referenced as `$1` in the replacement; add your regex sans anchors
- `.*$` - eat up anything that is left
- if you expect newlines in your input string use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`, e.g. start with `^[\s\S]*?` and end with `[\s\S]*$`